# SharePoint Crawling Job Problem

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I got this error when II see the crawl log. Can somebody explain?

> Crawling this document could not be
>   completed because the remote server
>   did not respond within the specified
>   timeout. Try crawling the server
>   later, or increase the timeout value.
>   You may also try scheduling crawls
>   during off-peak usage times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with crawling with "incremental crawl" option ? Try it once and let us know result.